# Cannot import anymore PouchDB in my project

Tags: node.js, typescript, pouchdb, typescript-typings

I am working on a project and recently PouchDB decided to stop working. I can't compile it anymore in my ts project. I tried:

```
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

export default PouchDB.defaults({
  prefix: `http://admin:password@localhost:5984/`
})
```

but I get

```
server/src/database.ts(3,24): error TS2339: Property 'defaults' does not exist on type 'typeof 'pouchdb''.
```

If I try :

```
import {PouchDB} from 'pouchdb';

export default PouchDB.defaults({
  prefix: `http://admin:password@localhost:5984/`
} as any)
```

I get

```
server/src/database.ts(1,9): error TS2305: Module ''pouchdb'' has no exported member 'PouchDB'.
```

If I try :

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

export default PouchDB.defaults({
  prefix: `http://admin:password@localhost:5984/`
} as any)
```

Then it will compile but I get this when I run it:

```
export default PouchDB.defaults({
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> ...
```

If I try :

```
 const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
```

I lose every typing, so it becomes a `any` type which i obv do not want

```
❯ npm ls pouchdb @types/pouchdb
compactd@0.0.0 /mnt/c/Users/Vincent/Documents/GitHub/compactd
├── @types/pouchdb@6.3.0
└── pouchdb@6.3.4
```

The only thing I did before it stopped working was cleaning node_modules and reinstalling using npm instead of yarn (yarn wants to recompile all my native modules every time I install something but I feel like npm is doing the same)

I tried downgrading PouchDB to 6.2.0, I have tried everything this is driving me crazy any help would be really appreciated.

Using ts-node, I tried to require/import PouchDB every way possible:

```
> require('pouchdb')
{ [Function: PouchDB$5]
  super_:
   { [Function: AbstractPouchDB]
     super_:
      { [Function: EventEmitter]
        EventEmitter: [Object],
        usingDomains: true,
        defaultMaxListeners: [Getter/Setter],
        init: [Function],
        listenerCount: [Function] } },
  adapters:...

> import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'
undefined
> PouchDB
undefined

> import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb'
[eval].ts:2
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
                      ^

ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at [eval].ts:2:23
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:53:29)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:59:15)
    at _eval (/home/vincent/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/_bin.js:181:29)
    at REPLServer.replEval (/home/vincent/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/_bin.js:220:18)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:440:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:210:7)

> import {PouchDB} from 'pouchdb'
Thrown: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
[eval].ts (1,9): Module ''pouchdb'' has no exported member 'PouchDB'. (2305)
```

Comment: My guess is that you had an older version of PouchDB in your node_modules folder, and that it's interface changed. Perhaps try importing (or requiring) that module in a `node` or `ts-node` REPL?  Then you can log your PouchDB object and see what properties are available on it.  That's not going to fix the problem if your type definitions don't match up, but maybe it could help find a version of PouchDB and @types/PouchDB that line up

Comment: @NathanWilson After debugging a lot, I found that the definitions I want are in `pouchdb/lib/index.es` which is present since 6.0.5. Of course, I can't import the .es file directly, no typings found. Trying to install 6.0.4 right now ...

Comment: Nvm, still doesn't work with 6.0.4 ...

Answer (score 2):

As of now, the best fix is:

```
import Pouch from 'pouchdb';
const PouchDB: typeof Pouch = require('pouchdb');
```

This is quick and dirty, but the real fix needs to be done by pouchDB maintainer